# 500 Internal Server Error on MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

Why am I getting an error in my file processApplication.php?

I am just trying to use my database class to get a MySQL connection so I can prepare my SQL statement before I execute it.

The variables, `$_POST['status']`, `$currentDate`, and `$_POST['id']` do have values as I've tested this without using the database class but instead using a `mysqli_connect` statement.

Any help please?

**processApplication.php**

```
<?PHP
include_once '../lib/variables.php';
include_once '../lib/database.php';

//make sure user is valid
if(check_ses_vars() != '') {

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$currentDate = date('m/d/Y');


$query = "UPDATE Application SET hasBeenPushed = ?, pushedDate = ? WHERE applicationId = ?";

$db = Database::get();

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt -> bind_param("isi", $_POST['status'], $currentDate, $_POST['id']);
$results = $stmt->execute();

}
?>
```

**And Database.php:**

```
include_once "variables.php";

class Database {

var $database_name;
var $database_user;
var $database_pass;
var $database_host; 
var $database_link;
private static $instance;

function Database($user=null, $pass=null, $host=null, $name=null)
{       
    $this->database_user = isset($user)?$user:$GLOBALS["db_user"];
    $this->database_pass = isset($pass)?$pass:$GLOBALS["db_pass"];
    $this->database_host = isset($host)?$host:$GLOBALS["db_host"];
    $this->database_name = isset($name)?$name:$GLOBALS["db_name"];
}

public static function get()
{
    if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
        $c = __CLASS__;
        self::$instance = new $c;
        self::$instance->connect();
    }

    return self::$instance; 
}

function connect()
{
    $this->database_link = new mysqli(
        $this->database_host,
        $this->database_user,
        $this->database_pass,
        $this->database_name
    );

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($this->database_link)) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What do the server error logs say?

Comment: Not related to the problem, but why are you generating an `m/d/Y` date in PHP? Storing that into a mysql date/datetime field will just lead to an invalid 0000-00-00 date at best. If that field is a varchar, then you SHOULD be using a native mysql date/datetime type anyways, and could just use `now()` to have mysql generate the date internally, insteading of forcing php to build a string, then forcing mysql to deconstruct that string.

Comment: I don't see anything related to processApplication.php in my error log.

Comment: There ALLWAYS is a error message on a 500. If not, you have to fix your PHP/Webserver configuration first. If you do a `phpinfo()` what does the `error_log` value contain?

Comment: I am facing the same error and my error log value contains `no value`. I am a beginner.Also, pls tell me how to view the error log.

Answer (score 1):

`$stmt -> bind_param("isi", $_POST['status'], $currentDate, $_POST['id']);` the spaces should create a parse error like `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)`?